# Find the value of $u'(1)+w'(1)$ using graph

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two functions whose graphs are shown, let $u(x)=f(g(x)) $ and $w(x)=g(g(x))$, then find the value of $u'(1)+w'(1)$

[image]

Isn't the data given in graph insufficient to find $g(1)$? We only know $(2,0)$ lies on $g(x)$ but we need another point to find the equation of $g(x)$ in $x \in [0,2]$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$g(x)=\frac{3}{4}(x-2)$ for $x\leq 2$ and $g(x)=-3x+6$ for $0\leq x \leq 2$.

$g(x=1)=3$. Hence, $u'(x=1)=f'(3)=(3-4)/(6-2)$ and $w'(x=1)=g'(3)=(3-0)/(6-2)$

Comment: How did you find it for $x \leq 2?$

Comment: Assumed an intersection at %(0,6)$.